# indexes with TypeORM and PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, postgresql, typeorm

In which case does TypeORM create indexes for a PostgreSQL database itself?

Does he do it himself when we have thoses TypeORM annotations :

- @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
- @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, @OneToOne, @ManyToMany
- @Column({ unique: true })

And is it useful to use composite indexes if they already have an index individual ?

Example with composite indexes :

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Index } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
@Index(["firstName", "lastName"])
@Index(["firstName", "middleName", "lastName"], { unique: true })
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Column()
    middleName: string

    @Column()
    lastName: string
}
```

Example with individual indexes :

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Index } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Index()
    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Index()
    @Column()
    middleName: string

    @Index()
    @Column()
    lastName: string
}
```

Maybe we should mixed it :

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Index } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
@Index(["firstName", "lastName"])
@Index(["firstName", "middleName", "lastName"], { unique: true })
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Index()
    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Index()
    @Column()
    middleName: string

    @Index()
    @Column()
    lastName: string
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know if for @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, @OneToOne, @ManyToMany or @Column({ unique: true }) Typeorm create indexes, maybe it depends on the DB at least for my case I'm using MSSQL and Typeorm (or the DB itself) create the primary key index.

If you want to create and index you should use the annotation @Index of Typorm.

In my experience using composite indexes increased the performance for the queries. I think you should just know how to create the index itself.